# Why my jquery UI resizeable doesn't work?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

my code is very simple

```
<div id="test"></div>

$( "#test" ).resizable().draggable();
```

the drag effect could work,but the resizeble doesn't work ,why?

here is example http://jsfiddle.net/udgGn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not including the jQuery UI theme stylesheets: http://jsfiddle.net/udgGn/2/